# MySQL connection error in configuration file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to connect to mysql database using php and following is my configuration file.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$db = "payroll"
$username ="root";
$password = "";

mysql_connect ($host,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($db,$username);
?>
```

but when I run my program it gives me this error:

> SQL error: No database selected SQL errno: 1046
>
> SQL: select language, admin from user where username='admin' and password='abc123'

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a semicolon here

```
$db = "payroll";
               ^--- Here
```

Don't forget to enable error reporting on your code. [`This is how you do it.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917)

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

---

### Switch to Prepared Statements..

A kickstart example..

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=payroll;host=localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

try
{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password ,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Read more here on [`PHP Manual`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqlhost="localhost"; // MySQL-Host
$mysqluser="user"; // MySQL-User
$mysqlpwd="password"; // Password

$connection=mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd) or die
("Couldn´t connect");
$mysqldb="database"; // Your Database
mysql_select_db($mysqldb, $connection) or die("Couldnt select database");
```

I always use this. Here you get every errormessage you need to find your error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$db = "payroll"
$username ="root";
$password = "";
$con = mysql_connect ($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db,$con);
?>
```